# How to replace column values to most frequent in groups in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas DF like this:

```
ID category
-----------
1  A
1  A
1  B
1  A
2  A
2  A
2  B
2  B
3  B
3  B
3  C
3  A
```

Now I would like to get a version of it where `category` column values are updated to the most frequent per `ID`. So the desired output is:

```
ID category
-----------
1  A
1  A
1  A
1  A
2  B
2  B
2  B
2  B
3  B
3  B
3  B
3  B
```

(In case an equal number of discrete elements happen to occure in `category` per `ID`, any of the values is acceptable.) What is the respective Pandas expression to use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `df['category'] = df.groupby('ID')['category'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])`